# Removing commas from a text file

Tags: java

Im trying to remove all commas from my text file, where am i going wrong? I think its to do with the replaceAll field, ive done research into it, but cannot find any answers. I also need there to be a new line after a ";" as well as removing the commas. Thankyou in advance

```
`public static void open(){
     // The name of the file to open.
    String fileName = "Test.txt";
    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = null;

    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            line.replaceAll(",","\\.");

            System.out.println(line);
        }   
        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();         
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + fileName + "'");                  
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable in Java, so `System.out.println(line.replaceAll(",","\\."))` is what you want.  You want to print the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

```
line.replaceAll(",","\\.");
```

Java Strings are immutable - this does **not** alter `line` but returns a new String with the desired replacement applied. Try assigning that to a variable instead:

```
String s = line.replaceAll(",","\\.");
```

or printing it directly:

```
System.out.println(line.replaceAll(",","\\."));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
String s = line.replaceAll(",","\\.");
```

Note Java strings are immutable

or you may choose to directly print it as:

```
System.out.println(line.replaceAll(",","\\."));
```

In you code when you say:

```
line.replaceAll(",","\\.");
```

then there is no change in the line and it returns a new String.

Answer (score 0):

changing `line.replaceAll(",","\\.");` to `line = line.replaceAll(",","\\.");` should fix your  problem.

As for putting newlines after ";" use `line = line.replaceAll(";",";\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Try to load file with :

```
public static String readAllText(String filename) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)).forEach(sb::append);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

then change what do you want.

```
String file = readAllText("myfile.txt");
file = file.replace(",","\\.);
```